# PYTHONSTARTUP doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, startup

I'm trying to use the PYTHONSTARTUP environmental variable. I set it to be "c:\python25\pythonstartup.py" in My Computer --> Advanced etc., and it doesn't seem to work.

Opening IDLE doesn't run the script, although it recognized the variable:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP']
'c:\\python25\\pythonstartup.py'
>>>
```

I'm using XP and Python 2.5.2. I do not wish to upgrade to 3.0 yet.

Thanks

Comment: Also, you must start IDLE using the -s command line option (see http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html#command-line-usage).  I found no way to add this option to the IDLE Start Menu entry on Windows 7, so I created my own shortcut as follows: C:\Python27\pythonw.exe C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py -s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html) says that PYTHONSTARTUP is only run for interactive sessions. I'm not sure how IDLE runs the Python interpreter, but it could be interfering.

Instead, try running `python` directly from a command prompt, rather than from clicking on an icon.

Comment: You are correct. I'll try to look for a IDLE startup file of some sort. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Greg Hewgill's correct answer: If IDLE doesn't have a startup file of its own, you can put a file called [`sitecustomize.py`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/site.html) in your path which will be executed for both command prompt and scripts / IDLE sessions.