# How to Pre-load Python Modules in Python IDLE on Startup?

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

I am on Windows 7.  When I launch Python **IDLE**, I want it to pre-load: `pandas`, `numpy` and `matplotlib` without me having to type out the import statements.  I import them very frequently.

I have waded through several posts:

[This one has to do with iPython, not IDLE-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124578/automatically-import-modules-when-entering-the-python-or-ipython-interpreter)

[This one has to do with running a script in IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247471/how-to-run-a-python-script-from-idle-interactive-shell)

[This one talks about PYTHONSTARTUP for interactive sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453808/pythonstartup-doesnt-seem-to-work)

From these posts, I have determined that there is a distinct difference between Windows command-prompt python interactive shell and IDLE's interactive shell.

For example, I created `defaultimports.py` and put it in this location:

`C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\jaradspythonstartup`

That script contains the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print('pd, np and plt imported')
```

Next, on my machine, I went to `Start` > `Computer` > right-clicked `Properties` > `Advanced system settings` > `environment variables` > clicked `New...` and added a new `variable` named `PYTHONSTARTUP`, then put my `path` `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\jaradspythonstartup\defaultimports.py`

[image: pythonstartup environment variable]

**However, this seems to only work in Windows Command prompt when I open command prompt and type `python`.**  I do see it loads my print statement.

[image: Imported Successfully in command prompt]

When I launch IDLE, I don't see the message: `pd, np, and plt imported` print statement.  While in IDLE, if I `import os` and `os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP']`, I do see my environment variable defined but don't know if that's important to note or not.

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP']
'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\jaradspythonstartup\\defaultimports.py'
>>>
```

**My Question**

**How can I pre-load modules in IDLE on startup?**

Comment: I think you can achieve this by adding a sitecustomize.py file somewhere in your path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`python -m idlelib -h` on a command line, where `python` runs recent 3.x, will display startup commands for IDLE; use `idlelib.idle` for 2.x. It says that

`idle idlelib -s` "runs $IDLESTARTUP or $PYTHONSTARTUP before anything else".

If that does not work, try `python -m idlelib -s`.

Currently, when you restart the shell, which happens when you run a file from the editor, ....STARTUP does not get re-run.  I hope to fix that.

EDIT: How to start IDLE with arguments from the desktop instead of command line.

1. Make a properly labelled IDLE desktop icon.  Go to Start Menu > Python x.y > IDLE... and copy to Desktop.  Control-Left Mouse Button drag or (Win 7, at least) Right click, Send to > Desktop (create shortcut).  If for Python before 3.4, right click icon, select Rename, and label with the version number.  (We recently got complaint "I installed 3.5 and (pre-existing) desktop icon opens 2.7.).
2. Make icon open IDLE with arguments.  Right-click icon, select properties, click end (you may or may not have to click box first).  Cursor should be at end of line with `...pythonw.exe...idlew.py`. Space and add arguments.  I tried `-c "print('hello')"` to test.  Add `-s` for ...STARTUP.   Consider renaming to indicate addition, such as `IDLE 3.5 64 bit STARTUP`, in case you want another IDLE desktop icon.

Comment: I determined that the target for desktop icons can be edited to include startup arguments.  See edit.

Comment: Edit the box called `target`.  It has the equivalent of a command line ('start idlew.py with pythonw.exe') and that is where to add arguments. `Start in` is the directory.  For my icon, this is blank and should be left blank.